# ARKit node disappear after 100m

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, arkit, scncamera

I'm currently working on ARKit (SceneKit) app. I've noticed that if I put a node at `100`m, the node will show just fine but if I set it to `101`m or farther, it won't show.

Is this the distance limit?

```
var translation = matrix_identity_float4x4
translation.columns.3.x = 1
translation.columns.3.y = 1
translation.columns.3.z = -100
let transform = simd_mul(currentFrame.camera.transform, translation)
let anchor = ARAnchor(name: "test", transform: transform)
sceneView.session.add(anchor: anchor)
```

Is there any way to increase this range?

Answer (score 3):

For increasing a Camera's range use `Far` attribute in `Z Clipping` area of Attributes Inspector.

The default value is `100` meters.

[image]

```
var zFar: Double { get set }
```

> Excerpt from [Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scncamera/1436596-zfar): The `far` value determines the maximal distance between the camera and a visible surface. If a surface is farther from the camera than this distance, the surface is clipped and does not appear. The default far value is `100.0`.

```
let camera = SCNCamera()
camera.zFar = 1000
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52886638/arkit-render-objects-further-away-than-1000-meters/55760812#55760812) provides an important info.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your very well detailed answer. That explains the 100m limit. My issue is that I'm using SpriteKit and not SceneKit. There is no SCNCamera. The only thing close to it I found is SKCameraNode but it doesn't have the zFar property.

Comment: Maybe you're having `SCNScene()` and/or `SK3DNode()`? Are you simultaneously using SpriteKit and SceneKit modules, or just SpriteKit itself (without SceneKit at all)? What's scene's type in your project: `Scene.sks` or `Scene.scn`?

Comment: I wanted to show just few very simple 2D elements so I created a SpriteKit project via Xcode. It created automatically Scene.sks file. It's kind of surprising I don't find a way to do it on SpriteKit.

Comment: That's ok. SpriteKit is a 2D framework. But! Do you have any `SCN` components in your `SKS` scene? Any.

Comment: No since I used ARSKView, it uses SKNode and Scene.sks scene file. ARSKView doesn't even allow me to use a Scene.scn file.

Comment: Try to use it via SK3DNode(). Or just use `SK` inside `SCNView`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181841/discussion-between-gigantic-and-pierre23).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no way to update the Z maximum range for SpriteKit. Only SceneKit allows you to modify this by updating the `zfar` property from the camera. Thanks to Gigantic for your help!