# ARKit – Render objects further away than 1000 meters

Tags: swift, camera, scenekit, augmented-reality, arkit

I'm trying to render objects further away than 1000.

```
let box = SCNBox(width: 500, height: 500, length: 500, chamferRadius: 0)
let boxNode = SCNNode(geometry: box)
boxNode.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -2000)
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(boxNode)
```

From this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536580/get-camera-field-of-view-in-ios-11-arkit) I know that ARKit directly sets SCNCamera's projectionTransform. So is there anyway I change this projectionTransform in order to render objects further away?

Answer (score 1):

In `ARKit` | `SceneKit` app, if a distance from ARCamera to 3D model is greater than `1000 meters` SceneKit's shader violently begins flickering, and approximately at `1600 meters` model disappears completely.

[image]

ARCamera doesn't render application's 3D content. This shader's artifact is SceneKit's rendering engine issue. So, you have nothing to do with that at the moment.