# Project Point method: converting rawFeaturePoint to Screen Space

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

Hi all I am trying to understand the values that are returned to me when I use ARKit's `projectPoint` function.

My goal is to take a point, `p = (x,y,z)`, where all values in the tuple are in range `[-1, 1]` and convert it to `p' = (x',y')` where all values in the pair are in range `[0,1]`, i.e. project from world space onto screen/image space.

I know that `arframe.camera.imageResolution = (1920.0, 1440.0)`, and
I know that my screen size is `(390.0 ,844.0)`

So, when I use the function I write: `arframe.camera.projectPoint(point: p, orientation: .portrait, viewportSize: arframe.camera.imageResolution`

This returns `(x, y)` but it is the case that `x > 1440.0` and `y > 1920.0` sometimes.
Furthermore, sometimes, `x` and `y` are negative values.

I am confused about how the function returns values that are greater than the viewportsize we gave. I am also confused by why the values themselves are negative.

The documentation provided by apple states the function 'returns the projection of a point from the 3D world space detected by ARKit into the 2D space of a view rendering the scene.'

What does '2D space of a view rendering the scene' mean more explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Theory

```
func projectPoint(_ point: simd_float3, 
              orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, 
             viewportSize: CGSize) -> CGPoint
```

> Xcode tip says – instance method `projectPoint(...)` returns the projection of the specified point into a 2D pixel coordinate space whose origin is in the upper left corner and whose size matches that of the viewportSize parameter.

The difference between `Screen Size` and `Viewport size` is described **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66828300/arkit-on-different-iphones/66828695#66828695)** and **[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60731258/arkit-viewport-size-vs-real-screen-resolution/60788960#60788960)** (I see you said you know about that).

### Solution

The trick is that the 2D point is projected correctly only when the 3D point is inside the [frustum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788280/ios-arkit-node-disappear-after-100m)'s coverage area of ​​the camera – it's not a secret that the distance is calculated according to the Pythagorean theorem...

```
import ARKit
 
extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        
        let point = simd_float3(0.3, 0.5,-2.0)
        
        if self.sceneView.isNode(self.sphere,
                             insideFrustumOf: self.sceneView.pointOfView!) {
            
            let pp = frame.camera.projectPoint(point,
                                  orientation: .portrait,
                                 viewportSize: CGSize(width: 375, height: 812))

            self.label_A.text = String(format: "%.2f", pp.x / 375)
            self.label_B.text = String(format: "%.2f", pp.y / 812)
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, outputting values ​​in normalized coordinates (`0.00 ... 1.00`) is very simple:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    @IBOutlet var label_A: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var label_B: UILabel!
    let sphere = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.1))
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.session.delegate = self
        sceneView.scene = SCNScene()
        
        sphere.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.green
        sphere.position = SCNVector3(0.3, 0.5,-2.0)
        sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(sphere)
        
        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        sceneView.session.run(config)
    }
}
```

I used iPhone X parameters – vertical viewportSize is 375 x 812.

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for the response. However, I am not using `SCNScene` so I cannot easily check if a point, `p`, is inside the camera’s futurism. Instead do you think I can filter points based on the value, `v`, the `projectPoint()` function returned, i.e. if `0 < v.x < screenWidth` and `0 < v.y < screenHeight` then I know that `p` is inside the futurism of the camera.

Comment: Hi Nicholas. You did not explicitly indicate which rendering framework you are using, so I concluded that ARKIt + SceneKit.

Comment: Here's an awesome resource with a math for plane extraction – https://web.archive.org/web/20120531231005/http://crazyjoke.free.fr/doc/3D/plane%20extraction.pdf